# LED outdoor light, randomly off and on

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, flashing

I've seen a lot of similar issues on this site to this but nothing that really answers the question or doesn't apply.

I've purchased a couple Outdoor LED boxes to replace some old outdoor sodium bulb boxes. Two LED boxes, connected to a light switch inside the house. Installation was simple, Black wire, White wire, Green Ground. Installed them by coping the removal of the old one.

Both lights, when I turn them on they will randomly (can be 15 minutes, can be 30 minutes or any amount of time between) turn themselves off and immediately turn back on. When doing this, they are not in sync. They are independent when it comes to the blinking.

First I thought it was due to the photocell reflecting off the porch roof. So, I disconnected the photocell on both of them and it still happens.

Any advice would be great.

The light in question: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07T83P3XV/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_fabc_NEQFX9KAX0Z76X7T53YD?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T83P3XV)

Comment: What model or brand? Some motion sensor lights run a calibration cycle this may be what you are seeing, the light at the sensor is different for each light so that may affect the timing of the calibration cycle but without a brand & model that would be my best guess.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the power on 24x7 for a couple days?  Your eyes auto-adjust to day vs night. Photocells do not, and actual lux levels can change quite a bit from one location to the next.  If they used the usual chip, they have a timer/memory and will learn over a 24-hour period what *normal* lux levels are in your location.  That means don't turn them off manually, or they lose their memory and have to start over lol.

Comment: So I have took your suggestion. I tried leaving it on for 24 hours both with the photocells on and the photocells disconnected. I'm still having the issue.